# Daily backup of kafka avro schemas

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-blob-storage

I am running kafka on kubernetes cluster (Azure AKS) and wondering if there is a specific method or best practice on how to backup and restore schemas stored in kafka topic to azure blob storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the Confluent Schema Registry?

The topic is raw json key-value pairs, so can be consumed and written to blob storage using Kafka Connect or any consumer

[Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/OneCricketeer/a12b4d9b26f0f2df4bee10cdc9c16d5d) I wrote few years ago (never used in production, though)